# how to get array button to a place on form?

Tags: c#

```
private Button[,] arrButton = new Button[10, 10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        arrButton[i, j] = new Button();//getting System.IndexOutOfRangeException
        arrButton[i, j].Size = new Size(30, 30);
        arrButton[i, j].Location = new Point(i * 30, j * 30);
        arrButton[i, j].Click += new EventHandler(arrButton_Click);
        this.Controls.Add(arrButton[i, j]);
    }
}
this.ClientSize = new Size(300, 300);
```

After create, array button come up top left corner on form.
how to get array button to a place on form

Comment: change 'for (int j = 0; i < 10; j++)' to 'j<10', and see if it works..

Comment: Your original question was to solve an IndexOutOfRangeException, which answers provided helped solved.  You have then changed your question when you should have created a brand new question.

Answer (score 3):

@choz comment is correct, but a couple things to also consider.

1. Put the row value and column value in constant variables and use the variables, instead of directly using a number repeatedly.

Example:

```
private const ROW = 10;
private const COL = 10;

private Button[,] arrButton = new Button[ROW, COL];

...

for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) 
{
    // Change from your code -|
    //              |----------
    //              V
    for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
    {
        // Create your buttons
    }
}
```

2. If you are going to use constant numerals, then reference the `GetUpperBound()` from your array to know the last index value of each dimension.

Example:

```
private Button[,] arrButton = new Button[10, 10];

...

// GetUpperBound(0) = last index of rows (9 in this case)
for (int i = 0; i <= arrButton.GetUpperBound(0); i++) 
{
    // Change from your code -|
    //              |----------
    //              V    GetUpperBound(1) = last index of columns (9 in this case)
    for (int j = 0; j <= arrButton.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
    {
        // Create your buttons
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error! Your second loop should be:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
```

You put "i" instead of "j",

Answer (score -1):

Normally, when you get an System.IndexOutOfRangeException. The debugger error is telling you that the loop or loops you are using are counting the elements more than you specific. Check The count of elements you tinkering with.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are making a mistake in inner loop. Can you please paste this and try to run:

```
private Button[,] arrButton = new Button[10, 10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)//Changed i to j
    {
        arrButton[i, j] = new Button();
        arrButton[i, j].Size = new Size(30, 30);
        arrButton[i, j].Location = new Point(i * 30, j * 30);
        arrButton[i, j].Click += new EventHandler(arrButton_Click);
        this.Controls.Add(arrButton[i, j]);
    }
}
this.ClientSize = new Size(300, 300);
```